# ¿Porque marca error "500 internal server error", en una llamada Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net

Estoy intentando hacer una llamada Ajax, pero me marca 500 internal server error, no he podido encontrar dónde está el error, aquí dejo mi código:

```
debugger
            $("#NotificaSolo").click(function () {
                debugger

                var table = $('#Notificar').DataTable();
                var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
                    return item[3]
                });
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "Formularios.aspx/EnviarCorreo",
                        data: JSON.stringify(ids),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (response) { alert(response.d); },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("ERROR " + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                        }
                    });
                return ids;
            });
```

y mi WebMethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public string EnviarCorreo(string ids)
        {
            XmlSerializer xml_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cLogin));
            StringReader string_reader = new StringReader(CookieUtils.LeeValorCookie(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nombreCookie"]));
            cLogin myLogin = (cLogin)xml_serializer.Deserialize(string_reader);
            string_reader.Close();
            try
            {
                String regresa = String.Empty;
                String[] valores = ids.Split(',');

                var ahora = DateTime.Now;
                var send = new SendGrid2(string.Format("Aviso {0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ahora));
                for (int i = 0; i < valores.Length; i++)
                {
                    send.AgregarDestinatario(valores[i]);
                    send.De = new EmailAddress("sistema@checkapp", "CheckApp web");
                    //send.De = new EmailAddress(cuenta, "CheckApp web");
                    send.AgregarLinea("Tiene una encuesta pendiente");
                    send.AgregarLinea("No responder, mensaje enviado automáticamente");
                    bool enviado = true;
                    if (enviado == send.EnviarMensaje())
                    {
                        string mensaje = string.Empty;
                        //mensaje = "<script>javascript:alert(' No se encontraron datos');</script>)";
                        clsCtaMail cuenta = new clsCtaMail();
                        //                    cuenta.direccion = txtUser.Text;
                        cuenta.activa = true;
                        cuenta.idUsuario = myLogin.UsrId;
                        cuenta.empresa = myLogin.EmpId;
                        cuenta.GuardaCuenta();
                    }
                    else
                        enviado = false;
                }
                return  "Enviado";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
                return "Fallido";
            }
        }
```

> jquery.min.js:4 POST
>   http://localhost:15147/Formularios.aspx/EnviarCorreo 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Has probado en poner todo el código en el bloque `try/catch` y hacer un log en un archivo al menos? Para mi que el error está entre las cuatro primeras líneas del `WebMethod`

Comment: Puede que haya un error en la url que llamas: `Formularios.aspx/EnviarCorreo`. Si tú pruebas esa URL en el navegador ` http://localhost:15147/Formularios.aspx/EnviarCorreo` es posible que no funcione, por lo tanto, no funcionará tampoco en tu llamada Ajax.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra el error parece estar del lado del cliente, no en el servidor, ni si quiera puedo debuggear el método del servidor, no lo está llamando, agregue una captura de pantalla a la pregunta

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando agrego esa url al navegador, si me abre la página y funciona bien

Comment: Debes declarar como `static` tu `WebMethod `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo `WebMethod` incluido en un aspx debe declararse como `static`

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string EnviarCorreo(string ids)
```

Si no se declara de esa forma, no será accesible desde tu llamada `ajax`

Comment: Gracias Sergio, se me había pasado ese gran detalle,